# Trying to get random forest for text classification running

Tags: r, text-mining, random-forest

I'm trying to get a randomForest running for a school project. I am trying to build a test classifier, that predicts a category (column label) based on some text.

Curretly I am stuck as there seems to be a problem with my document term matrix.
This is the error:

```
> rfmodel <- randomForest(df$label, data = events_dtm)
Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

This is what the code currently looks like. The data is representative.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(caret)
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)

text = c("this is a random text",
         "another rnd text",
         "hi there",
         "not so rnd",
         "what's that?",
         "kinda boring",
         "this is a random text",
         "another rnd text",
         "hi there",
         "not so rnd",
         "what's that?",
         "kinda boring")

label = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(text= text, label=label)
df$label <- as.factor(df$label)
df$text <- as.character(df$text)

df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))

df <- df[1:5,]

as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(text = as.character(text)) -> type

data("stop_words")
type %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  mutate(word = SnowballC::wordStem(word)) -> type_tokens


type_tokens %>%
  count(ID, word) %>%
  cast_dtm(document = ID, term = word, value = n,
           weighting = weightTfIdf) -> type_dtm


print(type_dtm)

rfmodel <- randomForest(df$label, data = type_dtm)

print(rfmodel)

dfT <- data.frame(text= text)
dfT$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dfT))

as_tibble(dfT) %>%
  mutate(text = as.character(text)) -> typeT

typeT %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) -> typeT

typeT %>%
  count(ID, word) %>%
  cast_dtm(document = ID, term = word, value = n,
           weighting = weightTfIdf) -> typeT

pred_test <- predict(rfmodel, newdata = dfT, type = "class")

print(pred_test)
```

Since I am rather new to both random forest and R there probably is a conceptual mistake.
Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

First your randomForest call:
`rfmodel <- randomForest(df$label, data = type_dtm)`

You cannot call df$label and specify data type_dtm where the label is not present.
Secondly sparsematrices are not accepted by randomForest. You need to do something with that. You can solve that by merging the label info with the type_dtm. Search SO on how to do that. Thirdly, you tell randomForest that y = label, but either you need to give a formula interface like label ~ . and specify data = .... or you need to specify y and x as y = label and x = ... see `?randomForest` for more info.

All of these issues combined result in this error you receive. Start solving them one by one and when you get stuck again, post a question. Your code is a good start of creating a reproducible example so +1 for that effort.